# How to create a sense of motion in stereo audio

Tags: ffmpeg, audio

I have a :15 mono audio file of a car driving by.

What I would like to do is use that as the input to create a stereo audio file where the sound 'moves' from left speaker to right for better realism.

I know how to convert the file from 1 channel to 2.  What I don't know is how to change the audio in those channels to create the effect I am looking for.

I have audacity and ffmpeg and prefer the command line.  I am not an expert by any means.

I searched the Internet and could not find anything that addressed how to do this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/53069016/

Comment: The internet has literally thousands of sites showing how to do this. However, in the interests of pointing you the right direction, I'll migrate this to Sound Design, where it can be answered or closed as dupe.

Comment: Automated panning in Audacity: https://youtu.be/D6m0KtkxY7Q